# How to use useEffect? so it wont duplicates displayed products using filter function? Reactjs-redux

Tags: reactjs, loops, filter, react-hooks, use-effect

My data from menProducts coming from store component just loops too many. Meaning it duplicates or renders too many when using my filter function. I've read using useEffect can render it only once but I don't know how to trigger its effect.

```
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');
  const menProducts = useSelector((state) => state.menProducts);

    const SearchText = (event) => { <--- this function is for input search bar
      setFilter(event.target.value);
    }

    useEffect(() => { <--- ??
    
    }, []);

      let dataSearch = menProducts.filter(id => { <-----Filter function
      return Object.keys(id).some(key=>
          id[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(filter.toString().toLowerCase())
      )

  return (
    <main>

      {dataSearch.map((menproduct) => ( 
          <ProductMen key={menproduct}/> <---imported <ProductMen/> component is a component that use useDispatch for store reducer and it also displayed products.
        ))}
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: have you tried something as simple as this: https://pastebin.com/jrh5teVP    this should rerender when setFilter is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `useEffect` in this case, you just have to apply the filter at the right time like this:

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

const menProducts = useSelector((state) => state.menProducts);

const SearchText = (event) => {
    setFilter(event.target.value);
};

return (
    <main>
        {menProducts
            .filter((menproduct) =>
                Object.keys(menproduct).some((key) =>
                    menproduct[key]
                        .toString()
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .includes(filter.toString().toLowerCase())
                )
            )
            .map((menproduct) => (
                <ProductMen key={menproduct} />
            ))}
    </main>
);
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6lfqps?file=src/App.js

In the demo i've also included an alternative that use `useEffect` if you want to take a look at it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is I've tried many methods about filters but I guess I have a wrong question. Whenever I put the imported <ProductMen/> to the filteredProducts.map it displays too many times.   But when its just plain import <div><ProductMen/></div> and no key={menproduct} .. It displays just right. But of course it won't have any filter function..

Comment: Nevermind, I solved my issue by combining this page with filter function and productMen page into one component. I guess importing the productmen causes the duplicate displays. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");
const menProducts = useSelector((state) => state.menProducts);

  const searchText = (event) => {
    setFilter(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const dataSearch = (filter) =>
      menProducts.filter((id) => {
        // function
      });

    dataSearch(filter);
  }, [filter]);

  return (
    <main>
      {dataSearch.map((menproduct) => ( 
          <ProductMen key={menproduct}/> <---imported <ProductMen/> component is a component that use useDispatch for store reducer and it also displayed products.
        ))}
    </main>
  )
```

To use the `useEffect` hook you have to pass a function and a dependencies array.

In this case I've used an anonymous function and inside of that I've defined the function `dataSearch` and on the dependencies array I've just included the `filter` so each time the `filter` value changes the `useEffect` gets executed.

Comment: Thanks! the problem is whenever I put the <ProductMen/> to the filter.map. It suddenly duplicates the display data. But when its just imported as normal imports. It display the right qty of product.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved my issue by combining this page with filter function and productMen page into one component. I guess importing the productmen causes the duplicate displays. thanks